# How can I use the NRF24L01 modules without a library?

Tags: spi, nrf24l01+

The datasheet is too intimidating for me, and I dont want to use the libraries available. Hence, I am looking for some clarity on this matter.

Comment: You can use them as book marks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the NRF24L01 by writing the functionality that is currently within a library yourself (and strip of parts you do not use).

However, for this, you need to understand the library, and therefore high likely the datasheet too.

You also can start without looking at a library, but your only documentation source is the datasheet itself.

A NRF24L01 has a lot of possibilities (that is why the datasheet is so extensive), so writing the functionality yourself might be causing more time.

Comment: And given all the functionality to be implemented to do even basic stuff, they would probably still end up writing something that looks very much like a library.

Comment: Indeed I did. But it's opened up the module for me. I was just stuck on the SPI commands though. Specifically the SPI read operation. I just didn't look at the diagram.